# android json response key value, parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

i get a JSON response from a web service:

```
{"CoverageSearchByLatLongResult":{"HasTransmissionAreasWithSignal":true,"SwitchOffArea": 
{"OpenForVastApplications":false,"SeperateTileSetUrl":"http:\/\/myswitch.merged.stage.orchard.net.au\/geodatafiles\/SwitchOffArea\/442b8844-3c05-4548-9424-
 4fdafc1f3c62\/Seperate","HASStatus":"Future","HASStatement":"<p>The Household Assistance Scheme is not yet available in this switchover area. Eligible households will be sent a letter when the scheme opens in the Sydney area.<\/p>","SwitchOffDate":"31 December 2013","Events":{"MaximumProximity":6.864859435168742,"Items":[{"Name":"Test Event","Time":"Time","Url":"","Date":"Date","Address":"19a Boundary Street, Rushcutter...
```

so my question is, in android java how to ask for the key: CoverageSearchByLatLongResult

in ObjC in iphone , something like this:

```
  NSDictionary *coverageResult = [response objectForKey:@"CoverageSearchByLatLongResult"];
```

so basically im parsing a dictionary with a key, but that result i need to put it inside other dictionary,

[correct me if wrong, in java dictionaries are called maps?]

how to do this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the classes in the org.json package:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

With them you can do things like:

```
try {
    String jsonString = "YOUR JSON CONTENT";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject anotherObj = obj.getJSONObject("CoverageSearchByLatLongResult");
    boolean bool = anotherObj.getBoolean("HasTransmissionAreasWithSignal");

    JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("arrayKey");
    int i = jsonArray.getInt(0);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Java Maps map keys to values. As an example of their use:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("string key", 1);
map.put("another key", 3);
```