# Parse dynamic number of objects in JSON array

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to Parse some JSON formatted text, but i'm not quite sure how to handle a dynamic object name. I've been looking around on the web, and from what I can tell this is referred to as a dictionary or a MAP in java, however I cant quite figure out how to handle the dynamic length.

I've validated my JSON using http://jsonlint.com/, the code I am parsing is below.

```
{
"0": {
    "animal_name": "Yoshi",
    "animal_type": "Day Gecko",
    "animal_id": "1"
},
"1": {
    "animal_name": "Wigglesworth",
    "animal_type": "Bearded Dragon",
    "animal_id": "2"
},
"command": "login",
"owner_id": "1"
```

}

There are a few details at the start which is static, then animals are returned, and the number of animals is dynamic.

I can extract the first part (Command and Owner_ID), and I can extract the animals individually, but i'm not sure how to loop through the array of animals. I dont know how many animals there are, and if I try to refer to them dynamically it doenst compile.

This is the code I have used to grab animals from the object, I'm just struggling to make it dynamic.
[android json response key value, parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812152/android-json-response-key-value-parsing)

This is quite similar to another question I posted in IOS, so my solution is a little more developed but still not quite there.
[Parse nested JSON code in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024163/parse-nested-json-code-in-ios)

```
//parse the JSON header
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);

//extract the owner id from the login response
owner_id=jo.getInt("owner_id");

//if the server throws an error, pass this back
if (!jo.isNull("error"))
{
    //store to global variable
    server_response=jo.getString("error");
}
else
{   //we only look for animals if a valid owner has logged in
    if (owner_id>0)
    {   //loop through the sub items.
        //HELP PLEASE: THE x<=5 needs to change to loop to the number of dictionary items in the JSONObject JO
        for(int x=0; x<=5; x++){
            //Extract each animal
            //HELP PLEASE: The jo.getJSONObject needs to get a dynamic item, but if I put x in here, it doesnt compile
            JSONObject animal = jo.getJSONObject("1");

            String animal_name = new String();
            String animal_type = new String();
            int animal_id = 0;

            //try and extract pets
            animal_name=animal.getString("animal_name");
            animal_type=animal.getString("animal_type");
            animal_id=animal.getInt("animal_id");

            //To Do: This code will overwrite each animal with the last. Need so store in an array.
            //get shared preferences object
            SharedPreferences prefs = a03_home_page.this.getSharedPreferences("my_app_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            //store the data
            prefs.edit().putString("animal_name", animal_name).commit();
            prefs.edit().putString("animal_type", animal_type).commit();
            prefs.edit().putInt("animal_id", animal_id).commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend changing the JSON to use an Array.

```
{
"animals": [
  {
    "animal_name": "Yoshi",
    "animal_type": "Day Gecko",
    "animal_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "animal_name": "Wigglesworth",
    "animal_type": "Bearded Dragon",
    "animal_id": "2"
  }, {... more animals ...}
],
"command": "login",
"owner_id": "1"
}
```

Now, you could simply add the dynamic number of animals to the `JSONArray` "animals" and iterate over it using a `for-loop` and `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`

However, if you can't change the json to your purposes, you can iterate over the keys:

```
Iterator keys = json.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()){
   JSONObject animal = json.getJSONObject(keys.next());
  // do smth
}
```

the problem with this approach is, that you have to be careful with "command" and "owner_id", since that are no json objects. So you need some more logic in the while loop.

Comment: Hi. Iterating over the keys worked like a treat. I've posted the code below to help anyone else reading this thread.
        `animal_count=0;
int ServerObjectCount=0;
Iterator KeyLoop = jo.keys();
while(KeyLoop.hasNext())
{
KeyLoop.next();      ServerObjectCount++;
}
       
//subtract the two items which are known not to be animals     ServerObjectCount=ServerObjectCount-2;

Comment: @NickHardman good to hear that. Feel free to accept this as the answer, then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Changing the JSON as per your suggestion wasnt an option as this would have invalidated the iOS version code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object o = gson.fromJson(str, Object.class);
    List keys = new ArrayList();
    Collection values = null;
    if (o instanceof Map) {
        Map map = (Map) o;
        keys.addAll(map.keySet()); // collect keys at current level in hierarchy
        values = map.values();
    } else if (o instanceof Collection) {
        values = (Collection) o;
    }
    System.out.println(keys);// [CDG, ORY, LBG]
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(keys.get(i));
    }
```

As seen in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398204/how-to-parse-a-json-array-with-the-same-structure-but-different-names)

Answer (score 0):

```
String result=yourjsondata.toString();
```

First assign your json array like this

```
JSONArray jsar=new JSONArray(result);
```

then parse objects like this

```
for(int i=0;i<jsar.length;i++)
{
JSONObject jsobj=new JSONObject(jsar[i]);

String strcode=jsobj.get("code");

String strrate=jsobj.get("rate");

String strtitle=jsobj.get("title");

String strsubtitle=jsobj.get("subtitle");
}
```